# Naming conventions for AWS Lambdas intended for REST API access

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-lambda

I'm building an API with the Serverless framework. Endpoints are defined on Amazon API Gateway, where each signature is mapped to an individual Lambda.

What is a good naming convention for the Lambdas here?  For example, the candidates for `POST /user` could be:

- `userPost`
- `createUser`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Naming is always tough.

For general naming - this is a good answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/130104

In addition, the scope of the namespace of your lambda functions is a consideration - e.g. if **all** of your functions relate to users in application XYZ for enterprise ABC, then `create` is sufficient.

However, if you have lambda functions for both enterprises ABC & DEF, and each have multiple applications with user management and *may* need different `create` methods for different things, then you may need something like `AbcApplicationxyzCreateUser`.

One other comment - in English, `commandObject` (e.g. `createUser`) *reads* better and sounds more natural when said aloud compared to `objectCommand` (e.g. `userCreate`). But I have found it easier to have the contextual parts (e.g. *company* or *application* ; if needed, but better avoided if possible) at the start as it facilitates tools to organize methods better (`contextCommandObject` e.g. `AbcCoCustomerServiceAppCreateUser`).

In short, make it simple, avoid using anything that is implicitly obvious, but allow for distinguishing between different applications/systems/entities in the namespace if needed.

Comment: This is some of the most sensible advice I've read about naming is as long as I can remember!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP convention of `POST /User` is applicable more at gateway layer where the APIs are described, the backend function which does this is creating a user. The API which is exposed is one event source of many which could trigger this function. For example, the function can be invoked by a SNS event through any other sources in future. So naming the function based on what exactly it does (business logic) would be appropriate. Here `createUser` sounds well.

However, if this lambda is invoking other lambdas to orchestrate the separate unit of work involved, then we may name it differently too.

**Alternate Scenario**

If we design the API to be made of multiple lambda functions. For example, if we need createUser process ends up doing some other backend operational deeds too(especially in big corp enterprises). We may have a POST /user API gateway call a `createUserAPILambda` calling `userDatabaseLambda`, `sendWelcomeEmailLambda` and `assignProjectLambda`. The downstream functions may be individually reusable and may not be part of original API itself.

**Cookie cutters that can be used**

- If it does just one type of activity, name should be a verb qualifying that like `createUserAPILambda` or `createUser`
- If it does multiple activities the we may have a noun on which the operations are performed e.g. `userDatabaseLambda`.
- Keep the naming short enough but fully qualified with any cross cutting aspects which can vary, e.g. `createUser` was good enough initially but it became `createUserAPILambda` when we split it for improving re-usability.(Micro vs Nano)